# Share Repurchase and Bid ask Spread data

Tags: equities, historical-data, liquidity

I am doing a Quantitative Finance PhD and would like some insight on data collection. I'm looking for open market share repurchase data (UK) over the past 2-3 decades. Simultaneously, their bid-ask spread around the repurchase date. I understand that I can calculate liquidity using trading volume method(s) but would initially prefer bid-ask spreads.

I got in touch with a few data vendors and went low on luck. We don't have a bloomberg terminal at the university, and since they don't offer individual subscriptions, they've offered to sell data on an one-off sale. I would like to explore more options before paying for the data. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Best,

Alpha 13

Comment: Have you checked out Yahoo finance?

Comment: Hey User 13524, I've got YF as a fall back to use for liquidity measuring based on trade volume etc. But they lack specific historic bid-ask information or repurchase information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember reading a paper a while ago about estimating bid/ask spreads through high/low.

http://www3.nd.edu/~scorwin/papers/high-low_spreads.pdf

That might help, because free NBBO data might be hard to come by.

For repurchase data, S&P 500 buybacks are online, but you have to hunt around for the releases and compile it yourself it seems.

http://us.spindices.com/indices/equity/sp-500

Comment: Many Thanks @JasonN. The study definitely makes things much easier for me. I've found that all of my data requirements are fulfilled by the SDC Platinum Database. Although I've put a request at my institution to subscribe for it, the use of the model in the said study will add statistical innovation to my research.

Comment: @Alpha13 Do you have a URL I can look for it at? I have an interest in using high/lows to estimate slippage and that is how I can about the paper.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not exactly sure which URL your asking for. If it's the SDC Platinum database then here is the link to the product site http://thomsonreuters.com/sdc-platinum/

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo Finance might be the best source, you have a lot of information available, Date   Open    High    Low close   Volume  Adj Close*.

https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=VOD.L

Comment: Hey MattRZ. Thanks. I've got YF as a fall back to use for liquidity measuring based on trade volume etc. But they lack specific historic bid-ask information or repurchase information.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, @Alpha13, if you are still following this, Quantopian, a retail algo platform just added share buy-back data to their data catalog. I'm not affiliated with the company, but thought it might help you:

https://www.quantopian.com/posts/sneak-peek-using-a-quantopian-research-notebook-to-analyze-share-buyback-data